# Import submodule into project, edit source, pull edits to cloned repo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I am having some trouble with my Android Studio project. I have successfully imported Google's Volley repository from GitHub into my project using the terminal, but I also want to edit that imported source code (just need to change one line) and be able to push those changes along with the project I imported the module into.

Currently, I can push all of my changes to my main project to GitHub. GitHub just creates a linked folder that directs you to the Volley repository when you try to click it. But when I want to push the one line change I made to the Volley code, it wants me to push it to the main Volley repo.

To be clear, all I am trying to do is import the Volley library, change a line, then be able to pull that change when I clone my main project repo on another PC.

Do I need to fork Volley, make the change, and then import that repo as a module? Thanks!